Avoiding dupicate target file in Informatica
I am using flat file target in my workflow and populate the file using FileName property.
It works just fine, but also creates another file with just the headers in it.
I want to disable its creation but not sure how to do it. Output filename property in Informatica session
I tried removing Output filename property in the session, but it couldn't be empty.
Guide says that dynamic files are supposed to overwrite the one specified in properties, but it is not happening for some reason.
https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/designer-guide/mappings/creating-target-files-by-transaction/running-the-session.html

Hi - what are the names of the two files being created and in which directory (or directories) are they being created?

They are created in the same folder, which is specified in the $PMTargetFileDir. First one, has the headers only and the name is what is entered in Output Filename attribute. Second one, has all the data and it is populated in the field FileName in the Target itself.

Short answer: You can't.
Explanation: Informatica, before starting the data load, ensures the sources and targets are accessible. One of the tasks is to create the target file with the default name. Next, the data load happens - then your desired target file is created. Once job is done, the dummy file persists.
Workaround: add a Command task to your workflow that removes the default file.

Thank you for explaining. I was able to implement it as you advised.
